# Laravel when should I extend or include or write double code?

Tags: laravel

I'm working on a Laravel application and in the view I have a few lines of code that I need in multiple views.
So is it better to extend or include this in a layout or should I write the code multiple times?

the codes that I need to include are:

```
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
```

and a few more meta tags and texts.

So what is the best way to do it performance wise and Laravel structure wise?

Comment: in my opinion, create a folder like ''inc'' and than inside create ''header.blade.php'' and than inside the views where you need those lines, add '' @include('inc.header'')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I usually handle this.
I would create a `head.blade.php` file and put **styles, scripts, meta tags, etc**.
Then I would include it into my layout.

In `app.blade.php` I would do `@include('frontend.includes.head')`

For the rest of the view files, I would extend the app layout.

```
@extends('frontend.layouts.app')
...
```

Answer (score 2):

These lines usually go to the layout